Show Percentage in Apex-Chart Blazor
I am using blazor apex-chart in .net 8 Blazor Wasm
How can i see the percentage of each value in Blazor apex-chart, right now my code is this which is not working. i didn't see anything with this code.
DataLabels = new DataLabels
{
    Enabled = true,
    Formatter = @"function (val) {return val +"+ '\u0022' +"%" + '\u0022' +"}"
}


i want something like this but this code not working for me.

you could try this code: DataLabels = new DataLabels {     Enabled = true,     Formatter = @"function (val, opts) {         const total = opts.w.globals.seriesTotals.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);         return ((val / total) * 100).toFixed(1) + '%';     }",     Style = new DataLabelsStyle     {         Colors = new string[] { "#fff" }, // Optional: Set label colors         FontSize = "12px",                // Optional: Set label font size         FontFamily = "Arial, sans-serif"  // Optional: Set label font family     } }

Try instantiating the DataLabel like this :
DataLabels = new DataLabels
        {
            Enabled = true,
            Formatter = (val, opts) =>
            {
                //Change the total expression to match your aggregation
                var total = YourObjects.Sum(e => e.Value);
                var percentage = (val / total) * 100;
                return $"{percentage:F1}%";
            }
        }

You can use the same for the Toolitp property of ApexChartOptions<YourModel>.
